# how to get value from drag down input field and stored in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have three drop down input fields and I want to change the options depend upon the value of other input field. I want to get the value of 1st input field and send it through php query to get the relevant data in another input field.

Let's suppose I have three  input field. I want to get value of 1st input field and sent it to database to get value of 2nd input field through php query.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#first-dropdown").off("change").on("change", function(){

 $.ajax({
    'url':"getUrl.php",
    'data':{id:$("#first-dropdown").val()},
    'method':'POST',
    'success':function(data){
       $("select#second-dropdown").empty().html(function(){
        var output='<option value="">Choose value</option>';
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(data.options)){
         $.each(data.options, function(key, value) {
           output += '<option value="'+key+'">' + value + '</option>';
         });
        }
        return output;
        });

  })

})

</script>
</head>

<body>

<select id="first-dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">1</option>
  <option value="saab">2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">3</option>
  <option value="audi">4</option>
</select>
<select id="second-dropdown">

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and my gerUrl.php is:

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST['id']
  echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal? Show some code of your tries. SO is not a place to get free coding, but advice on how to improve your code. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in following way ,

This is your first dropdown and second

```
<select id="first-dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">1</option>
  <option value="saab">2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">3</option>
  <option value="audi">4</option>
</select>
<select id="second-dropdown">

</select>
```

Your JQuery code

```
$("#first-dropdown").off("change").on("change", function(){

 $.ajax({
    'url':"getUrl.php",
    'data':{id:$("#first-dropdown").val()},
    'method':'POST',
    'success':function(data){
       $("select#second-dropdown").empty().html(function(){
        var output='<option value="">Choose value</option>';
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(data.options)){
         $.each(data.options, function(key, value) {
           output += '<option value="'+key+'">' + value + '</option>';
         });
        }
        return output;
        });

  })

})
```

and your php controller code

```
$id = $_POST['id']
  //search for the value of second dropdown using this id and once you get ths send it back to ajax 
//suppose $dropdownOPtions has all the data you got for second dropdown
  $data['options'] = $dropdownOptions;    

echo json_encode($data);
```

Please let me know If you need something more :)

Comment: @HarrisKhan what problem you facing?

Comment: @HarrisKhan in ajax field do modification like this `'data':({id:$("#first-dropdown").val()}),` 
replace the data field in ajax request with this one Here I have put (  ).

Comment: @HarrisKhan and this is really a nice question .. :)